# What is the difference between an asymptotically stable rest point and a locally asymptotically stable rest point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider $x' = f(x)$ with flow $\varphi(t, x)$ and equilibrium point $e$. I know what it means for $e$ to be *asymptotically stable*: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x_0 \in B_{\delta}(e)$, we have $\forall t \ge 0: \varphi(t, x_0) \in B_{\epsilon}(e)$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} \varphi(t, x_0) = e.$

Yesterday I heard the term *locally asmymptotically stable* for the first time, in this theorem:

**Theorem:** Suppose $e$ is an equilibrum point and $Df(e)$ is Hurwitz. Then $e$ is locally asymptotically stable.

I have no idea what locally asymptotically stable could mean. Asymptotically stable is a local definition already, and I don't see how we could make it more local

Comment: Whoever said or wrote that probably meant the same thing.

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh so the definition of local asymptotic stability is my definition of asymptotic stability?

Comment: Well, that would be my *guess*. But it's impossible to tell, especially since you haven't provided the source of that formulation.

Comment: @HansLundmark Okay, thanks! This was just a theorem my professor wrote on the board.

Comment: I see. But then why are you asking strangers on the Internet instead of asking your professor directly? (I'm only half joking!)

Comment: @HansLundmark Haha you've got a good point. The reason is that I am behind with the class, so I am scared that if I go to office hours and ask, I may sound very stupid. I think this is not a good attitude to have and I should go ask anyway, but it's very difficult to fix.